# Unable to change Material UI table padding

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the `Table` component from the `react` library `material-ui`.
For some reason, each row, including the header, has a `24px` padding, top and bottom, which I can't override.
I already tried changing the style on all the underlying components with no success. Here is the code:

```
<Table>
    <TableHeader adjustForCheckbox={false} displaySelectAll={false} fixedHeader={true}>
        <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>id</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>number</TableHeaderColumn>
        </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody showRowHover={true} displayRowCheckbox={false}>
        {data.map(item => {
            return (
                <TableRow key={item.id}>
                    <TableRowColumn>{item.id}</TableRowColumn>
                    <TableRowColumn>{item.name}</TableRowColumn>
                    <TableRowColumn>{item.number}</TableRowColumn>
                </TableRow>
            );
        })}
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Any idea how which component's style needs to be changed in order to override this styling?

Answer (score 14):

This kind of requirements can be handled with overrides in Material UI as per below example:

Step 1: include following dependencies

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core'
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Step 2: Define custom css related changes as

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiTableCell: {
            root: {  //This can be referred from Material UI API documentation. 
                padding: '4px 8px',
                backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Step 3: Wrap your component or your code block with

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Table>
        <TableRow>
             <TableCell component="td" scope="row">
             </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </Table>
</ThemeProvider>
```

This is how we can override the Material UI style from our custom style. 
Happy Coding :)

Comment: Great post thank you - with my config it seems to effect all tables not just the ones wrapped.  Can you account for that?

Answer (score 4):

The issue was with the `height` property of both the `TableRow` and `TableHeaderColumn`/`TableRowColumn`. For some reason this property manifested itself as `padding-top/bottom`.

To make a long story short, set the `height` property on the row and columns.

Comment: Indeed for rows both TableRow and TableRowColumn needs to have a height value set in style for height to be affected beyond the default. Same goes for the table header where both TableRow and TableHeaderColumn needs a height value set in their style for the height to change.  This knowledge is useful for applications that require a dense layout presenting lots of data in a limited height. Such adjustment breaks Material UI intended spaciousness but can be a key enabler for a particular application.

Comment: A Fiddle here for experimenting: https://jsfiddle.net/mobimation/jp3s4159/

Answer (score 1):

```
you can set size and paading props in material ui table  

    import {Table,} from '@material-ui/core';
    
    <Table size="small" aria-label="a dense table"></Table>
```

refer this for more details : https://material-ui.com/api/table/

and make sure that elements inside the table row has small sizes .

Answer (score -2):

Indeed, there is a padding added in the `Table` component, [as seen here in the code of that component](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Table/Table.js#L12).

It cannot be overridden in `material-ui` API, and the context Theme variable `desktopGutter` is used in many places so I suggest not to change it.

What you can do is override that with a custom CSS item, that you will bundle with the rest of your CSS, either classic stylesheets or "react stye" with `Radium` or similar.

For example:

```
<Table id="mytable">...your material-ui JSX...</Table>
```

In the CSS:

```
#mytable .table {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

*Edit: my mistake, this is for the main table component, not the rows, but you can do something similar with the other components by watching in the developper tools which CSS path needs to be overriden.*

Comment: it doesn't work. It just adds more padding on top of the inherited padding. I tried setting the padding on both the table and the th tags with no luck